# Hardware needed for using a Wiimote as a computer mouse

Tags: wiimote

I am in charge of turning a Wiimote (Wii remote) into a computer mouse and I know this is possible. I have been told to use the library http://wiimotelib.codeplex.com/. To use that library, will it just be a Wiimote that I need to buy? Or will there also be some other Bluetooth or infrared device or sensor I need to attach to the computer to make the setup completely wireless? Can you lead me towards the starting point, please?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question at all.  This is "what hardware do I need to plug my wiimote into my computer"?

Comment: True, but I found few Wiimote questions here on stackOverflow that somehow helped me and made me think to ask an other question too. :)

Comment: If you want to use the InfraRed sensor, you will need a cordless sensorbar (which is just a bar with a series of infrared leds in it), they are quite cheap: http://www.ebgames.com.au/wii-141479-Wii-Wireless-Sensor-Bar-Nintendo-Wii

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a particular library's hardware needs, rather than actual code or programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link to the [guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20110110033048/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/coding4fun/archive/2007/03/14/1879033.aspx) on the site, it says there in the hardware requirements that you'll need **a compatible PC Bluetooth adapter and stack**

Comment: Yes you're right. I have read that I can connect the Wiimote to bluetooth enabled computer but Bluetooth should be Wiimote compatible. I have HP Pressario and also have read that some guy was successful in connecting Wiimote to HP computer. Once I will be connected using Bluetooth, do you think I can turn it into mouse using C# libraries? I think I will need to use 2 APIs. One for handling the Wiimote and second for handling mouse.

Comment: There is a guide here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2008/01/04/6984678.aspx that explains everything you need to do with example code

Answer (score 0):

The wiimote uses bluetooth to connect to your computer/wii. So if your computer does not have bluetooth, you will need to buy a bluetooth dongle. If you want to use the infrared tracking capabilities of the wiimote, you need a infrared emmiting light source (two actually). The Wii sensor bar is nothing more than two infrared LEDs. Candles or TV remotes do the trick as well. I suggest buying some infraded LEDs and building your own 'sensor bar'.

Comment: my job is just to turn the Wiimote into computer mouse. I don't care what can help me to do that but as my Laptop supports Bluetooth, I think I should go with it. I have just ordered the Wiimote and waiting for it. Are you sure I can get this done using Wiimote and Laptop bluettoth only?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't, i used the wiimote with my macbook's bluetooth and with a pc with a usb bluetooth dongle

Comment: You should note that the official Wiimote Sensor bar has more than 2 leds, it actually has 4, two groups of 2 this is to ensure that the wiimote picks them up, the wiimote is capable of tracking 4 individual points in the InfraRed camera, the software has to interpolate these to produce the overall position of the wiimote pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have to make your own app I have made a a program to do just this (actually it does a lot more than that) it too uses the wiimotelib opensource library, you can download my program here:

http://home.exetel.com.au/amurgshere/wiimouse.phtml

Its fully freeware to use in a commercial or non-commercial environment.

It provides automatic detection and installation of the wiimotes (with the Microsoft bluetooth stack only) and supports various modes, one of them being a mouse in windows, and supports multiple wiimotes and multiple pointers. It also has a few other modes, like a whiteboard mode so you can draw on the screen at the press of a button and so forth, a PP Joy mode for emulating a joystick using WiiMouse and the PPJoy joystick emulation drivers.

It also supports full scripting and even comes with a named pipe solution for writing program to connect to WiiMouse.

Read the readme for more information.

Contact me here if you wish:

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=1192317